# WP8 Phone and SMS events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Background Agent that needs to listen to the OS Environment and react to when I receive a Phone Call or an SMS message.

Once a Phone Call or SMS is received, I need to see the caller's phone number.

Is there anyway to do this? Does WP8 offer access to such API functionality?

All my Google searches returned negative results, so I'm only interested in responses by people who have encountered this problem as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to be possible with Windows Mobile (with an interceptor). However, this functionality has been protected in all versions of Windows Phone (7 and 8). I am assuming MS did this so that your app will not (and can not) interfere with Incoming Calls.

Comment: An interceptor was exactly what I was looking for, knowing it was possible in Windows Mobile. Fortunately, the project requirements have been changed and I no longer need this functionality :)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. You can't access the phone or SMS properties or events you want with the current SDK.